# Reuse usb package installed with npm in electron app

Tags: node.js, npm, usb, electron, node-usb

I have an atypical internet connection, sometimes I have it, but sometimes I do not and I need to save its use.
I need to use the [usb library for node](https://github.com/tessel/node-usb), I already have it installed in another node_modules (same operating system / same pc), but when I copy it from one node_modules to another it gives the error:

```
Error: Error en una rutina de inicialización de biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos (DLL).
\\?\D:\WindowsDev\CopyWatcher\node_modules\usb\src\binding\usb_bindings.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WindowsDev\CopyWatcher\node_modules\usb\usb.js:5:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\WindowsDev\CopyWatcher\node_modules\usb\usb.js:417:3)
```

Is it possible to do something like this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you copy only that library from the node_module folder?

Comment: Yes, i don't know the dependencies